# SQL query needed to combine many-to-one values into single result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have two database tables called Item and Property:

```
Item
--------
item_id
title

Property
--------
property_id
item_id
property_value
```

Each Item can be associated with any number of Property entries.

Is there an SQL/MySql query that could return Item data with its corresponding Property data within the same row?  (i.e. I'd like a query to return all data from these tables, formatted such that each row of the returned result contains all Item and related Property data of a particular item)

Is this possible?

Comment: What table structure are you wanting in the end?

Comment: You may want to provide some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the results being in one column, you can do something like:

```
SELECT i.item_id,
       group_concat(p.property_id, ':', p.property_value separator ';') as properties
FROM Item i INNER JOIN
     Property p
     ON i.item_id = p.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for this?:

```
SELECT *
FROM Item i INNER JOIN Property p
ON i.item_id = p.item_id
```

This will project item_id from both tables.  If you want to limit the columns, list them individually from each table.

Comment: I do not think so.  It seems OP wants dynamic `PIVOT`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, VBlades!  Unfortunately, I don't think this will work from me... I'd like all Property data for a given Item to be returned within the same row of the result.  (i.e. If I had 3 Property entries associated with the same Item entry, I think the above query would return 3 separate rows for it instead of combining them into one)

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake, read it wrong.  Will think about it.  Apologies.

Comment: @user1752396: PM 77-1 is correct, I think, generally this would be a PIVOT solution.  There is a solution here, but looks involved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table.  Must the data be in columns?  Or would one field with all the data delimited by a character be ok?